# How does docker login know what port(8081) Artifactory is running on?

Tags: docker, artifactory

Quick question: How does docker login (on Docker for Mac) know what port(8081) Artifactory is running on? The default port for docker registry seems to be 8080.

```
$ sudo docker login docker.artifactory
```

But this works with just the hosts file updates to point to the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo docker login docker.artifactory:8081
```

Comment: Nope. You don't need the 8081. That is the mystery. My guess is that there is a file analogous to /etc/services that specifies the port in the docker config somewhere. How docker login works with registries on different ports without specifying the port is the question.